# How to set multiple JAVA_OPTS options in startup.bat

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm-arguments

I am trying to pass multiple parameters when I start tomcat through **startup.bat**. I tried adding these lines at the top of startup.bat file, however they do not work.

```
set JAVA_OPTS="-Dapplication.home=E:\\webapp -Dfilepath=D:\\newFolder\\conf\\con.properties"
```

Initially I was running the application with just one parameter `-Dapplication.home=E:\\webapp` which worked fine. Now I need to pass another parameter and this method fails. Please advice.

---

On running, I get this exception a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\webapp -Dfilepath=D:\newFolder\conf\con.properties (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
```

The code is reading the entire segment as a single argument.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

try without quotes

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dapplication.home=E:\\webapp -Dfilepath=D:\\newFolder\\conf\\con.properties
```

should work

Answer (score 11):

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dapplication.home="E:\\webapp"

set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfilepath="D:\\newFolder\\conf\\con.properties"